# How to assign object in typescript and replace object name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a response coming in from the backend `data.response.details` and am trying to create a new object with the name `newMember` to replace `details` name. As well, I want to push all properties from `details` to `newMember`? How can I achieve these tasks using object assign?

```
main.ts

    public after(args: IResult , data: any) {
        const res: IResult = data.response.details;
                const newMember= Object.assign({}, res);
                return Promise.resolve(this.getInformation(args, newMember));
    }


data.response.details

    "patientProfile": {
                "firstName": "Rob",
                "lastName": "ALLen",
                "memberStatus": "Active"
                }
```

expected json should be

```
"newMember": {
"patientProfile": {
                    "firstName": "Rob",
                    "lastName": "ALLen",
                    "memberStatus": "Active"
                    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the specific problem? What are expected results?

Comment: You have done that already , whats the problem?

Comment: i was expecting to create newMember object inside response and sent it in promise but its not happening

Comment: There is clearly something missing in the explanation. No idea what specific problem is. Also we have no idea what `this.getInformation` returns

Comment: everything is working fine i have the data just trying to map data to new object

Comment: Something like this?? `const newObj= {newMember: null}; Object.assign(newObj.newMember, res);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do an assignment:

```
const newObj = { newMember: data.response.details };
```

Now `newObj.newMember` has all of the properties of `data.response.details`. Note that this creates a shallow copy of the details.

---

If for some reason you want to create a deep clone of the details since you're just using simple string values you can do:

```
const newObj = { newMember: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.response.details)) };
```

This is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Create an object with newMember property having res as value

```
 const newMember = Object.assign({},{"newMember": data.response.details});
```